# How to change the status value in orders api?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, rest-api

In the orders api of Magento 2, I'm sending status parameter as `completed`.

But I have custom status as "`ProdCompleted`.

So everytime I get `status="completed"` That's why I want that if api get parameter `status="completed"` then it should send the response for `status="ProdCompleted"`

> http://magentosite/rest/V1/orders

How can I do this? can I override the Orders API? If yes, then How can I override the orders API?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an after plugin for `magento\module-sales\Model\Order.php` for **getStatus()** and check if status="completed" replace with status="ProdCompleted.

I made a sample module for you

https://mage2gen.com/load/9f7af424-19b5-4551-b56c-aa3b0fab9489

I have not tested the code , let me know if you face any issue

Comment: yes checking...

Comment: public function afterGetStatus(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        //Your plugin code
    }

I got this code into Order.php, so can I add return $subject=ProdCompleted; OR return $result=ProdCompleted;

Comment: You need execute and  test